# F5 API call 'message': 'You must enter a view-by entity name'

Tags: api, f5

I'm running a API call for F5 big-ip:

```
r = requests.get("https://<ip-address>/mgmt/tm/analytics/cpu/report", auth=('admin', 'admin'), verify=False)
pprint.pprint(r.json())
```

OUTPUT:
{'apiError': 26214401,
'code': 400,
'errorStack': [],
'message': 'You must enter a view-by entity name'}

What is the entity name?

Comment: A quick google turns up this: https://devcentral.f5.com/s/question/0D51T00006i7gOy/dos-l7-report-via-icontrol-rest-api

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yup, thanks.
I had found the correct format.

Answer (score 1):

As the commenter suggests, that information is in the tmsh manual. [Here's the link to the specific report](https://clouddocs.f5.com/cli/tmsh-reference/latest/modules/analytics/analytics_cpu_report.html?highlight=view), which supports options slot or cpu. So that request would look like:

```
r = requests.get("https://<ip-address>/mgmt/tm/analytics/cpu/report?options=view-by,slot", auth=('admin', 'admin'), verify=False)
pprint.pprint(r.json())
```